# nginx web server returns strange characters when using another language other than english

Tags: nginx

I recently setup a nginx web server and decided to write some html in my own language (bulgarian) but upon refreshing the page it seems as nginx returns strange characters instead of the actual text. (connecting over https) [strange characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0cf4.png)

Comment: Is your html file UTF8 encoded? You can easily check the file encoding by opening with Notepad++

Comment: yes, it's UTF8 encoded

Comment: Is <meta charset="utf-8"> in your html <head>? Can you check the nginx log? /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: turns out it isn't in <head> so I'll try adding it and tell if it worked
edit: it worked

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a suggestion by Valeriu Ciuca telling me to check if meta charset="utf-8" was in my html head worked since it wasn't there and after adding it everything worked properly.

Comment: you should give him a vote

Comment: I would but how, im fairly new to stackoverflow.